# Which CSP implementation is more secure?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, appsec, content-security-policy

While implementing CSP, there are two options.

1. Implement CSP in the HTTP response header
2. Implement CSP using a meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">`

Out of the above two, which method is more secure and why? Why the other is less secure?

Comment: Useful link: [Content-Security-Policy Meta Tag - OWASP Cheat Sheet Series](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet.html#3-content-security-policy-meta-tag) - "Almost everything is still supported, including full XSS defenses. However, you will not be able to use framing protections, sandboxing, or a CSP violation logging endpoint."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say using headers is marginally more secure than a meta tag because:

1. Some CSP elements such as `report-to`/`report-uri` are not supported in meta tags (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-to for that specific example and following the comment from Fire Quacker, this more general guidance https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet.html#3-content-security-policy-meta-tag)
2. Using headers allows a client to view the CSP via a HEAD request without loading the page. This could allow the client to decide not to proceed to a GET request if it did not like the CSP content (I appreciate this may be marginal security benefit, or maybe no real benefit at all in most cases)